# Proving that $tr(A^*A)=tr(B^*B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

$A, B \in M_n(F)$ are unitarily equivalent. How do I use that to prove that $tr(A^*A)=tr(B^*B)$?

Additionally, how would I use that fact to prove that $\sum_{i,j}|A_{ij}|^2=\sum_{i,j}|B_{ij}|^2$?

Comment: What does $A*A$ mean (does it differ from $A^2$)?

Comment: Edited, was supposed to be the adjoint.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent, then there exists a unitary matrix $U$ such that $A=UBU^{-1}=UBU^*$. But then 
$$
A^*=(UBU^*)^*=(U^*)^*B^*U^*=UB^*U^*.
$$
So we have
$$
A^*A=UB^*U^*UBU^*=UB^*BU^*.
$$
Now what can you say about the trace of $A^*A=UB^*BU^*$ and the trace of $B^*B$?

For your second question, write $A^*A$ out in terms of the entries of the matrix $A=(A_{ij})$. For example, when $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, this would be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\overline{A_{11}} & \overline{A_{21}} \\
\overline{A_{12}} & \overline{A_{22}}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} \\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
|A_{11}|^2+|A_{21}|^2 & \overline{A_{11}}A_{12}+\overline{A_{21}}A_{22} \\
\overline{A_{12}}A_{11}+\overline{A_{22}}A_{21} & |A_{12}|^2+|A_{22}|^2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
What do you get for general $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the first part: if $B=U^*AU$ for unitary $U$, then $tr(A^*A)=tr(UU^*A^*UU^*A)=...$

Hint for the second part: the $ii$-th entry of the diagonal of $A^*A$ is equal to $\sum_j |A_{ji}|^2$, so calculating the trace yields...